# How to check if a Postgres 10 cluster is being replicated?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, database-replication, standby

I am in the process of writing a bash script to upgrade Postgres servers in our org from 9.6 to 10.4, under Ubuntu trusty. I've got the master upgrade done, but we have instances in dev, staging and production with and without standby servers. I know how to upgrade a standby server, but I am struggling with a generic way to determine if a master has standby's, and if so, their hostnames. Anybody done this already and can share some light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the master, you can see the listening standby servers in [`pg_stat_replication`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-REPLICATION-VIEW):

```
select client_addr, client_hostname from pg_stat_replication
```

On the standby, you can see the master in [`pg_stat_wal_receiver`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-WAL-RECEIVER-VIEW):

```
select conninfo from pg_stat_wal_receiver
```

Comment: `pg_stat_replication` issues on the master, added the standby equivalent to the answer

Comment: Bingo. That's what I needed. I can now use this to get what I want, a list of IP's for Salt minions that are running as database replicas. Now I can automate the upgrades. :)  

`sudo -u postgres psql -t -c "select to_json(client_addr) from pg_stat_replication;"`

Comment: Huh. So now I know I have the two servers running with one as master and the other as a hot standby. pg_basebackup ran fine with the replication credentials. But the select ... from pg_stat_replication returns nothing. Zip. ???

Comment: `pg_stat_replication` shows the active listeners. Did you start the sever with a `recovery.conf` that instructs it to start as a hot standby?

Comment: Ok, so that's the next step. LOL! :)

Comment: Everything works now, but that's just the base state. On the replicas, if I do an in-place upgrade of the database, and the config files are not touched, I should not have to do anything else? Or should I rm the files in the data directory (except for recovery.conf), do a pg_base_backup, restore the recovery.conf file and restart the server?

Comment: The recovery.conf is always required. Not sure when a base backup is required, definitely not within a major version (say 9.4.5 to 9.4.6)

Comment: Because it's a major version change the replicas have to be baselined again using either rsync or pg_basebackup. What I did find is that pg_upgradecluster using in-place upgrade does not work correctly. When it was finished I couldn't do pg_basebackup, it would only pick up some of the data.

Comment: Yeah, I never do in place upgrade. Export using `pg_dumpall` and import into the new version.

Comment: I ended up using pg_upgrade and --j 4. On my environment it's handling 1gb of data about every minute or so (45gb in 51min), not counting redoing the optimization data. The diff is that pg_upgrade wants the options in excruciating detail. But I'm done now. thanks!